# require a help to fix one of the issue in my code

Tags: scala

I have written small code for testing purpose. But it is giving error. But not sure why?
could someone help me on this.

```
class JointAccount (val balance: Long) {

 def displayBalance = println(balance)

 def withDrawl(amt: Int) = {
   balance -=amt
 }

 def deposit(amt: Int) = {
   balance -=amt
 }
}
```

The error is

error: ';' expected but def found def withDrawl(amt: Int) ={

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that syntactically correct? Why do you have those `**`?

Comment: Hi, There are no ** in this program. May be it might have come automatically

Comment: I highly suggest you first read a basic tutorial (`val` are not mutable, no return type defined for the functions, useless `;`, ...).

Comment: what is the error - please add it to the question.

Comment: I think `deposit` should be `balance +=amt` (if `balance` is a `var` of course)

Comment: error: ';' expected but def found   def withDrawl(amt: Int) ={

Comment: Yes. deposit  should be +.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val` -> `var`

Also, your deposit and withdrawl functions do the same thing so I've fixed that

```
class JointAccount (var balance: Long) {

 def displayBalance = println(balance)

 def withDrawl(amt: Int) = {
   balance -=amt
 }

 def deposit(amt: Int) = {
   balance +=amt
 }
}

val x = new JointAccount(123L)

x.deposit(4)
x.displayBalance
```

[See it working live here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/USoXoVZSTdWpbNQLLgthEg)

I must say though, this is very Java and not at all Scala, in terms of how you've chosen to implement it. Scala best practices recommend avoiding mutable variables and functions that return a `Unit`. Here's an example re-written version of your code:

```
case class JointAccount (balance: Long) {
 def withDrawl(amt: Int) = this.copy(balance = balance - amt)

 def deposit(amt: Int) = this.copy(balance = balance + amt)
 // alternative: def deposit(amt: Int) = JointAccount(balance + amt)
}

def displayBalance(ja: JointAccount) = println(ja.balance)

val x = JointAccount(123L)

displayBalance(x.deposit(4))
```

[See it working live here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6hz8bRTgSHSApomLXrmoLw)

In Scala, it is much better to have functions inside a class either return a number (in your case) or a new class which has an updated value.

Comment: Thanks James for providing solution and valuable suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to modify a immutable variable (`balance`) as cchantep told you.

Here is a trivial example that may get you started:

```
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
case class JointAccount (balance: Long) {
  def displayBalance = println(balance)
  def withDrawl(amt: Int) = JointAccount(balance - amt)
  def deposit(amt: Int) = JointAccount(balance + amt)
}

val a = JointAccount(1000)

println(a)
a.displayBalance
val b = (a withDrawl 500) deposit 500
println(b)
```

You can play with it here https://scalafiddle.io/sf/f8Usa20/5

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried with both  val and var. But, it was error

Comment: How did you tried? The code above compiles and print the result.

Comment: I was talking about my code where I have seen errors. Can